# Changing Listbox columns count in code behind WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

How can I change listbox columns count in run time this is my code

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="427,151,0,393" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="480" Name="lst" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" SelectionChanged="lst_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding ColCount}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 3):

You just have to Notify when your ColCount property has changed.
Be sure to send the event PropertyChanged (Your ViewModel has to inherite from INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public int  ColumnCount { get; private set; }

private void add()
    {
        ColumnCount += 1;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnCount"));
    }
```

It's work fine for me !